# "column ambigiously defined" error

Tags: sql, oracle, name-collision

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 ref1,
       table1 ref2,
       table2 ref3,
       table2 ref4,
       table3
 WHERE ref3.a = ref1.b , 
       ref4.a = ref2.b , 
       ref3.c = f, 
       ref4.c = d
```

and it works great, it gives me 1 record with all the columns I want.

Two of these columns have the same name but the latter one gets intuitively the extension _1, so the first column with that name has the name `frubberducks` and the second one has the name `frubberducks_1`, and that's great. I need a query that only gives me these two columns so I tried:

```
SELECT frubberducks
  FROM table1 ref1,
       table1 ref2,
       table2 ref3,
       table2 ref4,
       table3
 WHERE ref3.a = ref1.b , 
       ref4.a = ref2.b ,
       ref3.c = f , 
       ref4.c = d
```

and I get the error:

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: frubberducks_1 isn't an actual column name, it is an automatic alias for the second frubberducks field in your query result. But when you're trying to select frubberducks - Oracle can't guess what do you mean - ref1.frubberducks or ref2.frubberducks for example, and throws an error. Use table aliases with the column name and all will be fine :)

Comment: As a side note: The queries are syntactically incorrect. Conditions in the `WHERE` clause should be combined using logical operators, not comma. `and it works great` how come?

Comment: You should also start using explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of using the outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do that is using table aliases and column aliases as below

for one column:

```
SELECT ref1.frubberducks
FROM table1 ref1,table1 ref2,table2 ref3,table2 ref4,table3
WHERE ref3.a = ref1.b and ref4.a = ref2.b and ref3.c=f and ref4.c=d
```

for two columns with the same name:

```
SELECT ref1.frubberducks,
       ref2.frubberducks
FROM table1 ref1,table1 ref2,table2 ref3,table2 ref4,table3
WHERE ref3.a = ref1.b and ref4.a = ref2.b and ref3.c=f and ref4.c=d
```

for two columns with the same name and with column aliases:

```
SELECT ref1.frubberducks ref1frubberducks,
       ref2.frubberducks ref2frubberducks
FROM table1 ref1,table1 ref2,table2 ref3,table2 ref4,table3
WHERE ref3.a = ref1.b and ref4.a = ref2.b and ref3.c=f and ref4.c=d
```

Comment: Err, doesn't that only give you _one_ of the `frubberduck` columns?

Comment: Parado, you may want to re-read the question: " I need a query that only gives me these **two** columns".

Comment: @Parado in the condition , is the comma correct all the time ?. It is the first time I Know we can add a comma instead of using 'and', but is it a good practice ? and is there other then comma we can use in conditions ? like in ur example comma replaced the and is there something replace the 'or' ?

Comment: @Moudiz I've missed that :) It's not correctly it should be `and` instead of comma, thanks for comment!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to be explicit such as with:

```
SELECT ref1.frubberducks as frubberducks,
       ref3.frubberducks as frubberducks_1 ...
```

`select *` means you want everything and you're not overly concerned about where it is in the result set. If you *did* care, you'd be explicitly listing the columns. There are precious few cases where you should actually use `select *` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's because if you specify which column you want to get in return, you have to specify them unambiguously.

So it should look like

```
SELECT ref1.frubberducks, ref2.frubberducks as frubberducks_1
FROM table1 ref1,table1 ref2,table2 ref3,table2 ref4,table3
WHERE ref3.a = ref1.b , ref4.a = ref2.b , ref3.c=f , ref4.c=d
```